# How to store the result of checkbox true/false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have got load of checkboxes which are by default checked. If user uncheck it then should store the value of it. How to do it?
Here I'm giving code for all elements are already checked.

```
$scope.isAllRecordSelected = function(record) {
  var checked = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
    if (record === $scope.users[i]) {
      checked = true;

      $scope.users[i].selected = checked;
    }


  }
  return checked;
};
```

html :

```
<div ng-repeat="record in users">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isAllSelected"                          
              ng-change="userSelectedToggle()"             
              ng-checked="isAllRecordSelected(record)">             
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="text-overflow">
      <span ng-model="record.dispalyName">  
             {{record.displayName}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <span ng-model="record.mobile">  {{record.mobile}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maintain an array of size: `$scope.users.length;`  and set their value as `true/false` whenever someone is checking/unchecking the checkbox

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: If you have written the code in question then I am very sure, you can do what I suggested. It's pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a key called `selected` in your users array which will keep track of the checked/unchecked values. You have to call your `isAllRecordSelected()` by default on page load so that every checkbox will be checked. Now you can keep count of checked/unchecked checkbox based on select key.

**HTML**:

```
 <div ng-repeat="record in users">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isAllSelected"                          
              ng-change="userSelectedToggle($index)"             
              ng-checked="record.selected ">             
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class="text-overflow">
      <span ng-model="record.dispalyName">  
             {{record.displayName}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <span ng-model="record.mobile">  {{record.mobile}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS** :

```
$scope.isAllRecordSelected = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++) {
        $scope.users[i].selected = true;
    }
}
$scope.userSelectedToggle = function(index) {
    if ($scope.users[index].selected)
        $scope.users[index].selected = false;
    else
        $scope.users[index].selected = true;
}
$scope.isAllRecordSelected();//initialise all checkbox as checked
```